# x-coredata:// last tag meaning

Tags: cocoa, core-data

I was just wondering what the last tag (/p645) of any core-data objectID means:

```
<x-coredata://D19E8AC2-90CE-47D1-B33E-4D73988B79CC/CDEvent/p645>
```

is this some kind of retain or access counter?

thanks
b00tsy

Comment: It's what's known as an "implementation detail". Leave it alone.

Answer (score 4):

Any meaning that the `objectID` has beyond uniquely identifying an object is private.  In other words, you should ignore the actual value of the ID, and instead just use it as an opaque object.

Comment: I don't want to make any use of the value, I just wondered why that last tag keeps changing from time to time...

Comment: @b00tsy: Changing on the same object?

Answer (score 0):

A quick rundown incase someone has need of it:

```
x-coredata:// -> CoreData URL Scheme
D19E8AC2-90CE-47D1-B33E-4D73988B79CC/ -> Store UUID
CDEvent/ -> ManagedObjectClass
p645 -> Object Instance, equivalent to the row of the table.
```